# Can 48x48 or 64x64 icons be obtained from the Vista Shell?

Tags: delphi

If 48x48 or 64x64 icons are present in the Vista Shell how can you get the handle to display one in a TImage using SHGetFileInfo?

I'd like to select an icon from a imagelist that represents a folder path and display a 48x48 or 64x64 icon in a Timage.

```
// load the large system image for the current path into Image1
SHGetFileInfo( PChar( CurrentPath ), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, SFI,
             SizeOf( TSHFileInfo ), SHGFI_ICON or SHGFI_LARGEICON or SHGFI_SHELLICONSIZE or
             SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX or SHGFI_TYPENAME or SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME );
AImageIndex := SFI.iIcon;
ImageList2.GetBitmap( AImageIndex, Image1.Picture.Bitmap );
```

Bill

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You must use the [SHGetImageList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762185%28VS.85%29.aspx) function, to get the image list with the larger icons.

Here you have an example in delphi

```
uses ShellApi, Commctrl, ShlObj;

const
  SHIL_LARGE     = $00;  //The image size is normally 32x32 pixels. However, if the Use large icons option is selected from the Effects section of the Appearance tab in Display Properties, the image is 48x48 pixels.
  SHIL_SMALL     = $01;  //These images are the Shell standard small icon size of 16x16, but the size can be customized by the user.
  SHIL_EXTRALARGE= $02;  //These images are the Shell standard extra-large icon size. This is typically 48x48, but the size can be customized by the user.
  SHIL_SYSSMALL  = $03;  //These images are the size specified by GetSystemMetrics called with SM_CXSMICON and GetSystemMetrics called with SM_CYSMICON.
  SHIL_JUMBO     = $04;  //Windows Vista and later. The image is normally 256x256 pixels.
  IID_IImageList: TGUID= '{46EB5926-582E-4017-9FDF-E8998DAA0950}';

function GetImageListSH(SHIL_FLAG:Cardinal): HIMAGELIST;
type
  _SHGetImageList = function (iImageList: integer; const riid: TGUID; var ppv: Pointer): hResult; stdcall;
var
  Handle        : THandle;
  SHGetImageList: _SHGetImageList;
begin
  Result:= 0;
  Handle:= LoadLibrary('Shell32.dll');
  if Handle<> S_OK then
  try
    SHGetImageList:= GetProcAddress(Handle, PChar(727));
    if Assigned(SHGetImageList) and (Win32Platform = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT) then
      SHGetImageList(SHIL_FLAG, IID_IImageList, Pointer(Result));
  finally
    FreeLibrary(Handle);
  end;
end;


Procedure GetIconFromFile(aFile:String; var aIcon : TIcon;SHIL_FLAG:Cardinal);
var
  aImgList    : HIMAGELIST;
  SFI         : TSHFileInfo;
Begin
    //Get the index of the imagelist
    SHGetFileInfo(PChar(aFile), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, SFI,
                 SizeOf( TSHFileInfo ), SHGFI_ICON or SHGFI_LARGEICON or SHGFI_SHELLICONSIZE or
                 SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX or SHGFI_TYPENAME or SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME );

    if not Assigned(aIcon) then
    aIcon:= TIcon.Create;
    //get the imagelist
    aImgList:= GetImageListSH(SHIL_FLAG);
    //extract the icon handle
    aIcon.Handle:= ImageList_GetIcon(aImgList, Pred(ImageList_GetImageCount(aImgList)), ILD_NORMAL);
End;
```

You can use these functions in this way

```
var
 hicon :TIcon;
begin
    hicon:= TIcon.Create;
    try
     GetIconFromFile('C:\Tools\reflector\readme.htm',hicon,SHIL_JUMBO);
     Image1.Picture.Icon.Assign(hIcon); //assign to timage
    finally
     hIcon.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: If someone is wondering (like me) how the index of the icon (`SFI.iIcon`) is used, then you should look at the [answer from Bill Miller](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1709686/256544) with the corrected code. Very helpful answer however!

Comment: +1 @splash. I was also wondering about this. does SHGetFileInfo changes the system image list and placing this icon as last? I still can't figure out how the above works without **using** `SFI`.

Comment: Used this code for populating an imagelist with 32x32 image size. some icons are incorrectly duplicated for different filetypes when for example two similar type of files exist in the folder. Wasted a day!

Answer (score 6):

Read [here:](http://pogopixels.com/blog/getting-the-48x48-or-256x256-icon-of-a-file-on-windows/) (Code in C++)

> Getting the 16×16 and 32×32 icons on
>   Windows is relatively easy and is
>   often as simple as one call to
>   ExtractIconEx.
>
> However, getting the extra large
>   (48×48) and jumbo (256×256) icons
>   introduced respectively by XP and
>   Vista is slighly more complex. This is
>   normally done by:
>
> 1. Getting the file information, in particular the icon index, for the
>      given file using SHGetFileInfo
> 2. Retrieving the system image list where all the icons are stored
> 3. Casting the image list to an IImageList interface and getting the
>      icon from there

Comment: i need pascal code not C++ but thanks anyway.  i found some pascal code but it is not filling the imagelist interface yet.

Comment: The C++ code just calls the Win32 API, it should be no brainer to convert it to Pascal.

Answer (score 4):

We found that the index of the file was not correct because the incorrect icon was shown during testing of the code posted by RRUZ.  The GetIconFromFile method was setting the index baised on the image count.  We changed GetIconFromFile to use the SFI index ( aIndex := SFI.iIcon ) and the correct icon was obtained.  Apparently the shellimagelist is constantly changing so the index was incorrect.

Thanks to all to assisted.  This seems like a very good piece of code now.

```
procedure GetIconFromFile( aFile: string; var aIcon: TIcon;SHIL_FLAG: Cardinal );
var
  aImgList: HIMAGELIST;
  SFI: TSHFileInfo;
  aIndex: integer;
begin // Get the index of the imagelist
  SHGetFileInfo( PChar( aFile ), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, SFI, SizeOf( TSHFileInfo ),
    SHGFI_ICON or SHGFI_LARGEICON or SHGFI_SHELLICONSIZE or SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX or SHGFI_TYPENAME or SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME );
  if not Assigned( aIcon ) then
    aIcon := TIcon.Create;
  // get the imagelist
  aImgList := GetImageListSH( SHIL_FLAG );
  // get index
  //aIndex := Pred( ImageList_GetImageCount( aImgList ) );
  aIndex := SFI.iIcon;
  // extract the icon handle
  aIcon.Handle := ImageList_GetIcon( aImgList, aIndex, ILD_NORMAL );
end;
```

Comment: Anyone know how to get a 64x64 icon from the systemimagelist using this code?

Comment: Yes, this code could correctly populate a TImageList as against the RRUZ code. I'm on XE5, Win7.

Answer (score 1):

[kicon](http://www.tkweb.eu/en/delphicomp/kicon.html)

i use the appropriate kicon method (**LoadFromFile**/**LoadFromModule**/**LoadFromModuleByIndex**) depending on the source file type.

if these methods fail, i use [PrivateExtractIconsA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648075%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> function PrivateExtractIcons(lpszFile: PChar; nIconIndex, cxIcon, cyIcon: integer; phicon: PHandle; piconid: PDWORD; nIcons, flags: DWORD): DWORD; stdcall; external 'user32.dll' name 'PrivateExtractIconsA';

and pass the resulting handle to kicon's **LoadFromHandle** method.

once it's been loaded into kicon, iterate over the icondata[] array to pick out the size you want.  kicon has methods to convert the returned image to PNG.