# Threaded loading of icons in Delphi

Tags: delphi, icons, delphi-2009

Using Delphi 2009, trying to make a launcher.
In order to make it "snappy" I would really like to load icons in a background thread.

I have used the solution found here :
[Can 48x48 or 64x64 icons be obtained from the Vista Shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703186/can-48x48-or-64x64-icons-be-obtained-from-the-vista-shell)

This works fine, if NOT run in a thread.
As soon as I put it in a thread, some icons are not "fetched", or being some kind of generic icon.
I even tried serializing the threads (making them obsolote, in effect) but it yields the same results.

So, the question is:
How do I load icons (with the same available options as the linked example) in a thread?

/Lars

Edit:
Added some very basic error-checking in GetIconFromFile

```
if SHGetFileInfo( PChar( aFile ),
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                SFI,
                SizeOf( TSHFileInfo ),
                SHGFI_ICON
                  or SHGFI_LARGEICON
                  or SHGFI_SHELLICONSIZE
                  or SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX
                  or SHGFI_TYPENAME
                  or SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME ) <> 0 then
begin
  if not Assigned( aIcon ) then
    aIcon := TIcon.Create;
  aImgList := GetImageListSH( SHIL_FLAG );
  aIndex := SFI.iIcon;
  if aImgList <> 0 then
    aIcon.Handle := ImageList_GetIcon( aImgList, aIndex, ILD_NORMAL );
end;
```

This doesn't make any diffenrence.
I am still getting some generic icons (only when this is called in a thread, though)

Edit2 :
Threading-code (very simple) :

```
procedure TIconLoader.Execute;
var
  Item : TGridItem;
  I : TIcon;
begin
  inherited;

  while not terminated do
  begin
    Item := nil;
    if assigned(FOnNeedGridItem) then
    begin
      Synchronize(
          procedure
          begin
            FOnNeedGridItem(Self, Item);
          end
      );
    end;

    if assigned(Item) then
    begin
      GetIconFromFile(Item.FFilename, I, SHIL_EXTRALARGE);
      Synchronize(
          procedure
          begin
            Item.SetIcon(I);
          end
      );
//      I.Free;
    end
    else
      Terminate;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Show what you got sofar, so we can help...

Comment: Well, not much to show. I have the procedures from the linked example. I have tried different thread-approaches, but everyone gives the same (wrong) result.

Comment: What errors are returned by the api calls? Did you initialise com?

Comment: No errors returned, at all. I call CoInitialize, but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: How did you check that there were no errors? The code that you link to has simply ignored error handling. Did you add error handling?

Comment: Oh, no, I haven't added any errorhandling to those procedures. I was (wrongfully) expecting exceptions.

Comment: Please show us the threading code...

Comment: You've added code, but you don't call `CoInitialize`. The documentation clearly states that you must. You said in a comment above that you had done so. Do you realise that the call to `CoInitialize` must be made from the thread which calls `SHGetFileInfo`?

Comment: I call CoInitialize(nil) in the threads constructor

Comment: The TThread constructor runs in the main thread!

Comment: This means you have to call CoInitialize in the execute part.

Comment: @LURD is right. You need to initialise com in the thread. That means inside Execute.

Comment: That was it! Thanks for pointing that out! ...though I feel stupid now... :-)

Comment: Please LURD or David or Lars, add this as an answer so it is more discoverable than in the comments. And @Lars: please accept it even if you add it yourself (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118042/a-way-to-reduce-criticism-and-down-voting-for-answering-your-own-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `SHGetFileInfo` specifies that you must initialize COM before calling the function. Since COM initialization is per-thread, you need to initialise COM in the thread. That means calling `CoInitialize` or `CoInitializeEx` from the `Execute` method of the thread.

Comment: You accepted the answer. Then unaccepted. Is there a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can simplify your threading code by using the TThread.Queue methods introduced in Delphi 2009.

An article which gives some examples and background information is here:

[Synchronize and Queue with Parameters](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2011/01/30/synchronize-and-queue-with-parameters/)

TThread.Queue is non-blocking. This allows to sequentially create background worker threads for all your icons and then let them load asynchronously.

Comment: I am practically 100% certain it's not a thread-code problem. I have a simple list of some simple objects, which holds a filename and a TIcon. I have tried making a thread per object, and the above where a thread is created, and being hand-fed the objects when needed. No matter how I call the GetIconFromFile from within a thread, it ends up giving me wrong icons. If I make the call from the main-thread, everything is fine... ??

Comment: Oh, and just for fun, I tried wrapping GetIconFromFile in a TCriticalSection. That didn't make any difference...

Answer (score -1):

Try moving this:

```
GetIconFromFile(Item.FFilename, I, SHIL_EXTRALARGE);
```

into `synchronize` block. And you should call [DestroyIcon()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) after using `SHGetFileInfo()`.

Comment: That would defeat the whole purpose of using a thread, wouldn't it?