# SHGetImageList & Icons 64x64

Tags: c++, delphi, winapi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can 48x48 or 64x64 icons be obtained from the Vista Shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703186/can-48x48-or-64x64-icons-be-obtained-from-the-vista-shell)

I would like to get 64x64 icons for Documents/Pictures/Music libraries. Explorer.exe is able to do it.

I use API function SHGetImageList and I don't have any problem to get 48x48 or 256x56 but I don't know  how to get 64x64 icons.

When I use SHGetImageList with SHIL_EXTRALARGE I get 48x48 and when with SHIL_JUMBO I get 256x256....

Is there any way how to get icons 64x64 for Documents/Pictures/Music libraries in W7 ???

thx

Comment: Have you tried the method described here: [Can 48x48 or 64x64 icons be obtained from the Vista Shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1705549/576719)

Comment: Don't you get the 256px image and downscale?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Incorrect assumption 256px = 64x.

Comment: @Xearinox that comment made little sense to me. Please elaborate.

Comment: Simple: I will create icon in icon editor, image for 64px will be one image but for 256px will be different. Now downscaling 256px icon not be the same as 64px.